# Remapping urls with jetty

Tags: java, jetty

My application's context root is /foobar and I am running an exploded deployment with maven-jetty-plugin.

I need to dynamically remap requets for /images/* to /foobar/images/*, and I cannot remap my application's context root to /.

For weblogic I have a halfwit solution where I deploy an additional war containing a proxy to context root /images.

The problem is that I cannot get this to work with maven-jetty-plugin, because I dont see how it can deploy two apps.

Anyone know how to do this  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to <img> links?  If so, it's a job for Apache's MOD_REWRITE

Comment: Yes I know. But there's no apache here and there will not be an apache. This is part of the rapid-turnaround development environment.

Answer (score 0):

http://jiajia.eu/category/Maven.aspx